# Creating a list of objects from the struct

Tags: c, list, for-loop, struct

My program will be a list of names and surnames.

I have a a struct which has attributes of name, surname, and a pointer to the next struct object.

In for loop I will add a new items to this 'list', just by writing new names in the command line (for that I will use scanf).

I would like to ask how co create this list?

So far I've created 1 object in which I can send the parameters, but it is just for 1 object.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your structure for storing a name is `struct name`. You'll probably have a variable to store the head of the list:

```
struct name *head;
```

We want to append to the end of the list. One way to do this would be to store a pointer to where we want to put the pointer to the next node:

```
struct name **tail = &head;
```

When we create a new name to append to the list, we can do something like this:

```
name->next = NULL;
*tail = name;
tail = &name->next;
```